# Best approach to connect a blazor server side .net core app from inside a linux container (docker) to an internal network Active Directory?

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, ldap, blazor-server-side

On some research I found some people have used this : https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard in a similar situation.

I was wondering if anyone has had the experience of using it with .net core 3.0 blazor - server side app?

Are there any other libraries/ recommendations?

Comment: It says `compatible .NET platforms: .NET Core >= 1.0`, why do you think it would not work?

Comment: Hi @VojtěchDohnal I wasn't implying on if it wouldn't work. Just trying to find the best practices around it or any other recommendations that someone else has tried out yet and willing to share. Thanks.

Comment: But recommendations are off topic on stackoverlow.